# How to place xaxis grid over spectrogram in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot, which provides the spectrogram of a pressure signal along with the signal placed on it for comparison. I was able to draw the y-axis grids on the spectrogram, but could not place the x-axis grid on it.

[image]

The data used to generate the spectrogram is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTcHJackZHZjNFY3M/view?usp=sharing).

**Reproducible code**

```
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib import ticker as mtick
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('pressure.dat', skiprows = 1, delimiter = '\t')
pressure = data[:, 1]
theta = data[:, 0]


with PdfPages('Spectorgram of cylinder pressure.pdf') as spectorgram_pressure:
    _spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency_ = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
    _spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency_.clf()
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency = plt.subplot(111)
    cax = plt.specgram(pressure * 100000, NFFT = 256, Fs = 90000, cmap=plt.cm.gist_heat, zorder = 1)
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.grid(False, which="major")
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.set_xlabel('Time (s)', labelpad=6)
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', labelpad=6)
    y_min, y_max = spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.get_ylim()
    # plt.gca
    cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical', ax = spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency, fraction = 0.046, pad = 0.2)
    cbar.set_label('Power spectral density (dB)', rotation=90)
    primary_ticks = len(spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.yaxis.get_major_ticks())
    pressure_vs_time = spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.twinx()
    pressure_vs_time.plot(((theta + 360) / (6 * 6600)), pressure, linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = '-', color = '#FFFFFF', zorder = 2)
    pressure_vs_time.grid(b = True, which='major', color='#FFFFFF', linestyle=':', linewidth = 0.3)
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.xaxis.grid(True, which='major', color='#FFFFFF', linestyle=':', linewidth = 0.3)
    pressure_vs_time.set_ylabel('Cylinder pressure (bar)', labelpad=6)
    pressure_vs_time.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LinearLocator(primary_ticks))
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.set_xlim([0, max(cax[2])])
    spectorgram_pressure.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

***How to place x-axis grids on top of the spectrogram like the y-axis grids in Python?*** I am using matplotlib version 1.3.1. ***Is this a version-specific problem?***

**Update**

I updated matplotlib from version 1.3.1 to 1.4.3, even then I cannot set the x-axis grids on.

Comment: if I run your code, I get gridlines in both the x and y directions. Do you have something set in your `matplotlibrc` that might be affecting things? Maybe try setting them to default values with `matplotlib.rcdefaults()`

Comment: Even in my matplotlibrc gridlines are on.

grid.color : FFFFFF
grid.linestyle : -
grid.linewidth : 0.5
grid.alpha : 1.0

Comment: What version of matplotlib?  Might be a version issue.

Comment: This is very puzzling.  It works fine for me in 1.4.3 - in 1.3.1 it causes an `ImportError`, but I guess that's irrelevant now you've updated matplotlib.  My only guess is that you must have something elsewhere overriding.  It seems you do have *some* different settings, because your font for the labelling is different to that produced on my pdf with default settings

Comment: I also get a black box around my colorbar unlike your image.  These slight differences are making me wonder what engine is rendering your pdf.  Can you give us a few more setup details - e.g. are you using `usetex` option - if so what OS are you on and what program is rendering the TeX?  Do you see the vertical lines if you render to screen (e.g. `plt.show()`)?  I can get similar problems to yours on screen with `plt.show()` if I take the line width down.  Have you tried increasing the linewidth in your calls to `grid()` and `xaxis.grid()`?  Try 1.5 ish.

Comment: I have set usetex to True, my OS is Ubuntu 14.04. No, I don't see any vertical lines if I render to screen or when I set linewidth to 1.5.

Comment: OK.  Two new differences that might give mesomething to work on :)  I can only easily test on Windows here and I see the lines on screen rendering and the pdf rendering will be different with `usetex`.  I'll try to get onto an Ubuntu box and try it out...

Comment: Works fine for me too. Ubuntu 12.04, matplotlib 1.4.3. Also with `usetex` switched on.
Your figure is still relatively complex. Could you try to make a minimal example? That will make it easier (also for yourself) to identify the problem.

Comment: @hitzg Do you get the x-axis grid to appear?

Comment: Yes, the x-axis  grid appears. I didn't change anything in your code.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `zorder`? Pass some high number e.g. `zorder=1000` to make sure that its not rendered behind the image.

Comment: No, it doesn't help.

Comment: OK - I fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit to a Virtual box, new install of packages `python-matplotlib` and if "all just worked".  I see the vertical x axis grid lines on screen and in the pdf.  Just in case, I tried setting `text.usetex=True` and rendering (had to install `livetex-latex-base`, `livetex-fonts-recommended` and `livetex-fonts-extra` and `livetex-latex-extra`).  This also worked both on screen and rendering to pdf.  I cannot reproduce your error.  Is there anything else unusual about your system?  Is this snippet of code part of something larger that you're doing with mpl?

Comment: Wondering if any of my suggestions helped, or if you have any further info about your setup / context of this code?

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted - it is very difficult to replicate your issue with the code you have provided.

In particular - I have tried on Windows 8.1, Ubuntu 14.04 (on Virtualbox VM), matplotlib versions 1.3.1 and 1.4.3, with and without `text.usetex` set and with Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.  None of them reproduce your problem with the code you provide.

#### However

I ***can*** reproduce what you see if I replace the line

```
spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.xaxis.grid(True, which='major', color='#FFFFFF', linestyle=':', linewidth = 0.3)
```

with

```
pressure_vs_time.xaxis.grid(True, which='major', color='#FFFFFF', linestyle=':', linewidth = 0.3)
```

i.e. I try to set the `xaxis.grid` on the twinned axis rather than the original axis.  I have to conclude that somehow in your real code you are setting the `xaxis.grid` on your twinned axis rather than your main axis.

---

This means I can answer your direct questions as follows:

> How to place x-axis grids on top of the spectrogram like the y-axis grids in Python?

Your code does this - you call `xaxis.grid()` on the original (not twinned) axis.

> I am using matplotlib version 1.3.1. Is this a version-specific problem?

No, the behaviour is the same in 1.3.1 and 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Though in my case (python3.4, matplotlib 1.4.2, Ubuntu 14) I see the x-gridlines, I guess you can try following:

```
[pressure_vs_time.xaxis.get_gridlines()[x].zorder for x in range(len(pressure_vs_time.xaxis.get_gridlines())) ]
```

this will give you the layer of your gridlines (upper have higher values, can also be negative). In my case it returns 2 for all lines. Than you can set:

```
[pressure_vs_time.xaxis.get_gridlines()[x].zorder = 1000 for x in range(len(pressure_vs_time.xaxis.get_gridlines())) ]
```

Comment: No problem for me with y-axis gridlines. X-axis gridlines are the problem.

Comment: See update. I see both. I just changed `yaxis` to `xaxis`. try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the code provided in your question and it works fine for me. I see both the x- and y-gridlines. Your code automatically saves a pdf version of the image. I converted this output to png. It looks like this

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 LTS, python 2.7.6, numpy 1.8.2 and matplotlib 1.3.1.